# Why letsencrypt SSL certificate display warning messages?

Tags: lets-encrypt

I'm new to letsencrypt SSL certificate.

I have followed the article [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04), but received the following warning messages upon loading the website :

```
Warning: stream_socket_client(): Peer certificate CN=`abc.com' did not match expected CN=`1.2.3.4' in /usr/share/nginx/html/wp-includes/class-wp-http-streams.php on line 150

Warning: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto in /usr/share/nginx/html/wp-includes/class-wp-http-streams.php on line 150

Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://1.2.3.4:443 (Unknown error) in /usr/share/nginx/html/wp-includes/class-wp-http-streams.php on line 150
```

Any clue on what's going on?

Comment: It seems that something wants to connect to `1.2.3.4` (an IP address) using SSL. This won't work unless you have a certificate for `1.2.3.4` (which is rare). You may want to connect instead to `abc.com` (a fully  qualified host name).

Comment: How to do it? is the issue related to my nginx configuration? or perhaps the letsencrypt SSL certificate itself?

Comment: You should provide more detail, as in *what program* gives those warnings, and in *what context*. All I can say from the question is that some program is trying to make an SSL connection to an IP address, not to a name. Certificates are usually (and Let's Encrypt certificates are *always*) given for names not IP addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer.

I modified my DNS control panel to use 2 nameservers, where previously there were 4 nameservers, from 2 different web hosting providers.

Then I tried :

```
sudo certbot --nginx -d abc.com -d www.abc.com --force-renewal
```

Refreshed the browser and voila, it works now.

Hopefully this will be useful to whom encounter the same problem.